# Imprimir 2 registros por página com Mpdf

Tags: php, codeigniter, mpdf

Meu problema é o seguinte: estou precisando imprimir duplicatas. Estou utilizando para gerar o pdf o `Mpdf`. Quando preciso emitir somente uma blz, funciona perfeitamente, mas quando preciso imprimir mais, corta, fica uma parte na primeira página e final na segunda.

Em uma folha `A4` cabem 2 duplicatas, então qual seria a melhor forma para eu resolver esse problema? Quando chegar exemplo: registro 2 muda de página, registro 4 muda, assim por diante.

Comment: Poste o código...

Comment: Sim com a dica do André

Comment: Eu tinha feito o código errado, dai eu corrigi e deu certo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$i = 1; // Número de registros mostrados, começa com 1 para não dar erro de divisão por 0.

foreach ($registros as $registro) {
    echo $registro; // Exibe o registro.

    if ($i % 2 == 0) // Se o número de registros mostrados for divisível por 2, quebra página. (2, 4, 6, 8).
        $mpdf->AddPage(); // $mpdf deve ser a instância do seu MPDF.

    $i++; // Acrescenta um ao contador de registros.
}
```